# Linkedin Session always return nil or invalid session

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch LinkedIn session through SDK but it always returns `nil`. I got success authentication but the session object is always `nil`. How can I fix this?

```
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil]
                                         state:@"some state"
                        showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                                  successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

                                      NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
                                      LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                      NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                                      NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[session.accessToken description]];
                                      [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",state=\"%@\"",returnState]];
                                      NSLog(@"Response label text %@",text);
                                      //_responseLabel.text = text;
                                      //self.lastError = nil;
                                      // retain cycle here?
                                     // [self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:NO];

                                  }
                                    errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"%s %@","error called! ", [error description]);
                                       // self.lastError = error;
                                        //  _responseLabel.text = [error description];
                                       // [self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:YES];
                                    }
     ];
```